# How to show multiple values in textbox or combo box

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, csv

I am having trouble with this.  I'm fairly new to MS Access (using 2003), so any response, please make simple.
I have a form with a combo box that I would like to show multiple values.  I have the combo box created, and it shows two columns (Column 0 = Practice Code, Column 1 = Practice Name).  The combo box is showing both columns nicely, but the problem I'm running into is that when I select multiple values, the Practice Codes (Column 0) display, but not the Practice Name like I want.

Currently, it's showing the code numbers
317, 314, etc (only the number (also primary key))

but I need it show the names - 
Practice Name 1, Practice Name 2

I have played around with the bound column numbers and it will always shows the code numbers, not the practice name.  I have also tried to link this up to a text box, which works, but will only show one value, instead of multiple names.

How do I get multiple values to show in one box?  I have this working on the table with the look up wizard, but can't get it to work on the form.

Comment: Combo boxes are there to show a single value (or perhaps a concatenation of multiple columns *of the same database row*). I suspect you need a control that is designed to show multiple values.

Comment: @Richard I think you may have misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the column widths in a combobox with more than one column, so for example:

```
Row source: SELECT Id, Description FROM MyTable
Column Widths: 0; 2
Bound Column: 1
```

This will hide the Id and show the description to the user. The value of the combobox will be Id.